# Changing color of a span (parent / this / ?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

sorry for the bad topic..

I'm trying to make a code that, when I put more than 3 characters in my text input I want a checkbox to turn green; I got a lot of these checkboxes and nothing seem to go as I want it to.

Hopefully someone out there has a better answer.

This is my html code:

```
<li class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon PaddingFix" id="basic-addon4">
    <strong>Username</strong>
  </span>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" placeholder="Username.">
  <span class="input-group-addon PaddingFix tooltipFix" data-placement="right" title="Fyll i ditt användarnamn.">
    <span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Like I said I want the color of the checkbox to change when there are more than 3 characters in the input

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() { 
    parent = $(this).parent().attr("class");

    if ($(this).val().length >= 3) { 
        $(".fa-check-square-o", parent).css({"color": "#08c004"});
    }
});
```

This is just one input, I have 12 more of them, that's why I tried to use "parent" as a selector; so I only change the color for just that "input-group."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest defining `parent` as the DOM element itself, rather than the element's class attribute.

```js
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
  parent = $(this).parent();

  if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
    $(".fa-check-square-o", parent).css({
      "color": "#08c004"
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon PaddingFix" id="basic-addon4"><strong>Username</strong></span>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" placeholder="Username."><span class="input-group-addon PaddingFix tooltipFix" data-placement="right" title="Fyll i ditt användarnamn."><span class="fa fa-check-square-o">check</span></span>
</li>
```

When using [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context), the "context" is defined as follows:

> **jQuery( selector [, context ] )**
>
> **context**
>   Type: Element or jQuery
>   A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Comment: God, embarrassing that i didn't figure that out <_>

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS with :

```
if ($(this).val().length >= 3) { 
    $("."+parent+" .fa-check-square-o").css({"color": "#08c004"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the dot (`.`) before class parent in selector, so you have to change :

```
$(".fa-check-square-o", parent).css({"color": "#08c004"});
```

To :

```
$(".fa-check-square-o, ."+parent).css({"color": "#08c004"});
```

And it will work.

Hope this helps.

---